# All figures have width equal to textwidth

Tags: floats

I am using the [AIAA typeset](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aiaa) for my LaTeX file.

I include figures as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.70]{XXX.eps}
\caption{XXX.}
\label{fig:XXX}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that all figures in my paper have figure width equal to the textwidth, that is, the scale command is completely ignored.

Is there a way I can still scale the figures, so that the width of my figures no longer equals the textwidth?

Comment: Have you tried, say, `\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{XXX.eps}`? This should set the width of the image to, you guessed it, 70 percent of the width of the text block.

Comment: @Mico An answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can still scale the figures, so that the width of my figures no longer equals the textwidth?

You could set, e.g.,

```
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{XXX.eps}
```

if you want the graph to occupy, you guessed it, 70% of the width of the text block.